# SQL Server 2000 query performance

Tags: performance, optimization, sql-server-2000, indexing

We have migrated our few serevr to named instance and I have a situation where a a Stored procedure is taking more time for execution.
stored procedure has some bussiness logic pointing to a table. I have indexes on the table. My doubt how same stored procedure, used on same table with same index in two different production databases taking different times. I understand that database performnce depend upon load onto the datbase. But I am exeuting in non bussiness hours and I think load also almost similar. Its taking 10sec for execution in new named instancwe server and 3 sec in old server. Do I need to defragment the table in new server. will it solve problem. Any idea how shall I check where is the problem in new server.

**Edit:** when I checked the execution plan it was giving 38% time of exection in eager spool(to create temorary index). Can you please explain me how I can avoid this part in exceutiuon.
I am not getting this whhile executing to the non named instance server(where its taking 3 sec for execution)

**Edit:** will re building of indexes make any performance improvement

Comment: We're going to need a lot more specifics to actually help you here.  We'd need to see your stored procedure, your table schema, execution plans, indexes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First check : check the execution plans for the queries on either server - do they match?

Edit : Plans do not match, so next thought is the schema (indexes) are not identical, or the stats on the newer instance are not up to date. try an sp_updatestats on the newer instance and see if the plan changes.

Comment: OK @andrew I already checked execution plan Please check edited part of my question.

Comment: Indexes on both the server are same and I have created an new stats on the newer instance server and when I checked I was able to see update date also. Can you please give me some more details about stats. thanks for the quick response..

Comment: shall I check the fragmentaion ration between the new server and old server. will it help me out. I think it will make a difference between the performance..

Comment: What's the difference in the IO subsystems between the two servers? Fragmentation could make a difference but depends how the data on this new instance was populated, backup / restore?

Comment: new is OS WIndows 2003 with SQL Server 2000 and old is OS windows 2000 with SQL Server 2000. do you need the same info or you want some other details.

Comment: new server was resotored with merge replication. and this happens only 1 weeke before.

Comment: Nothing obvious suggest why the plans are differing, assuming the same data, same schema, same stats - the plans should be the same - assuming the same SP of SQL Server as well.

Comment: assuming you are out of business hours / running on a test system, DBCC FREEPROCCACHE and DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS - e.g. clear the query plan cache and see if it comes back into the right plan.

Comment: I am not able to recraete the scenario in test region and stored procedure is taking just 1 secs for exection in test region.   thanks....thats fine andrew.. I will check it out... Can you please clear one small doubt. I have a table with Column_Id decalared as char(9) and I have a index on the column Column_Id. I am using this column in a stored procedure but by misatke I declaered a temporary variable of datatype char(10). Will index work when I will query the table against the column decare in stored procedure. means one is char(9) and other is char(10).

Comment: I suspect it will not work since the values would not be considered identical (always will be 1 char different)

Comment: Actually this is one of the problem in same stored procedure only. but these problem in present in both the production server. thanks.

Comment: I would delete this question and create a new one, with all these additional checks / information within it.

Comment: @@Andrew: Today when i closly looked at execution plan I noticed there was a difference between **"number of executes"** in execution plan. Do you have any idea about this. Is it possible to look into my other question..